# {latitude = Location.getLatitude (); longitude = Location.getLongitude ();

Tags: java, android, localization

I'm trying to find my location. 
It's working, but my localization is false !!

This is the class:

```
public class maaaap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    String[] g, s;
    double d1, d2, lat, A, latitude, longitude;
    LatLng l;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    LatLng tunis;
    Location mLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maaaap);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
       //  gpsTracker= new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
       //mLocation=gpsTracker.getLocation();
       // if(mLocation!=null){
        // latitude= mLocation.getLatitude();
       //  longitude= mLocation.getLongitude();
    }//}

    public void table() {
        g = new String[]{"36.827831", "36.836143", "36.832123"};
        s = new String[]{"10.144411", "10.143982", "10.150763"};
        //for (int i = 0;i <g.length; i++) {
        // la.add(g[i].toString());
        //lo.add(s[i].toString());

        // }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location!=null) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
           double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        table();


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            d1 = Double.valueOf(g[i]);
            d2 = Double.valueOf(s[i]);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(d1, d2)).title("kolha touness"));


        }

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(" touness"));

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does the app crash? Is there a crash log? If yes, then post it. Edit your question and explain your problem more precisely.

Comment: my problem is i want to get my place in the map with my longitude and my latitude and for confrimé that longitude and latitude contains values i add a marker of these coordinates
I applied the method all is well but the marker is show in another place that I am now

Comment: try to `Log` your latitude and longitude, and see if it's successfully obtained. It's probably not, you have to properly handle permissions, the code that obtains location should be inside the first `if` block in `onMapReady`.

Comment: I did not understand ?!

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see that you `return` if the permission is not granted. In that case, check if the location is successfully obtained, you can `Toast` the location, and see if it's obtained.